# PDF Solution that allows expandable text boxes

Tags: pdf, pdf-editor

I used to create PDF's with expandable text boxes in Adobe LifeCycle. I have checked and Adobe LifeCycle is no longer an option. I'm not looking for an overflow text box as it doesn't show the remained of the text, just a "+" icon at the bottom right.

Expandable text is sometimes important in the fields when more details are added but doesn't print a bunch of blank space when it isn't needed.

I have Adobe Pro but it doesn't allow for expandable text. Do you know of any commercial programs or a solution for creating the original PDF documents with this capability?

Answer (score 0):

These forms are called dynamic XFA forms and as far as I know only Adobe LiveCycle had support for creating them.